# How do I validate wurfl.xml?

Tags: mobile, wurfl

I'm wondering which is the best way to validate the wurfl.xml file.

I am thinking about these two different approaches :

- Since it is a XML file I can validate wurfl.xml against its XML schema. Some questions related with this are: from where do I get the xsd file?, how often does the xsd file change?.
- Query the wurfl database once the file is loaded and check the number of devices, or some other outstanding values. I will have to investigate this deeper and see which methods the wurfl api provides for that purpose.